# Gold Badge doesn't count up votes to Questions

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, badges

The gold php badge states that to obtain the badge you must have:

> Earned 1000 upvotes for answers in the php tag

However, should up votes to questions count as well? Being well-versed in a language is not only about answering questions, but also being able to ask good questions that can be useful to other people.

I fully expect this to be `status-bydesign`, as it is technically by-design, but I think it is something that should be looked at.

Answer (score 6):

I'm against it.

These badges are (in my mind, at least) intended to recognize accomplishment and expertness in the subject.

And while both asking and answering can demonstrate these qualities and both can also achieve votes without either quality, I think that answering correlates better.

No statistics, nothing remotely objective to back it up. It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

But that metric is *specifically* for people providing answers. I don't see what questions has to do with this at all.

Comment: The sidebar description: `You'll have to earn 1000 upvotes in non-community wiki questions to achieve this badge.`, does not at all reference that it is answers only.

Comment: The only way you would ever begin to even think that this mechanism is reserved only for providing answers only is reading each tag description. Both sidebar notes in no way point to the thought that it is answer only.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with this. Usually the questions that get voted up are usually not of the "how do i shot web" variety, but at least clever if not outright well-thought-up, and deserve to be applied towards the badge.